# Is it possible to install zoo-project in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu, zoo-project

I want to install zoo-project in Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), but it seems there aren't any programs to do that, for example I have a problem with zoo-kernel install because there is not "ibmozjs185-dev" for bionic. Which version of Ubuntu (14, 16 or 18) is suitable for installing zoo-project?

Comment: It states here that the download source package is not found.  No version of Ubuntu will work.   https://packages.debian.org/sid/libmozjs185-dev

Comment: Thanks, that's right. Today I was forced to change my ubuntu from 18.04 to 16.04 and installed it without any error especially in "ibmozjs185-dev" installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nickan

You could use the ppa from the OSGeoLive project.  They have a libmozjs and zoo-project for 18.04.

PPA is at https://launchpad.net/~osgeolive/+archive/ubuntu/release-12.0

Their github formula is at https://github.com/OSGeo/OSGeoLive